# when i try to load an object it shows me an error

Tags: javascript, three.js

the Error TypeError: THREE.GLTFLoader is not a constructor
at /script.js:5:14

```
 import { GLTFLoader } from "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.121.1/examples/jsm/loaders/GLTFLoader.js"
    let loader = new THREE.GLTFLoader();
    loader.load('scene.gltf', function(gltf){
      scene.add(gltf.scene);
      render.render(scene,camera);
    });
```

Comment: You're importing as `GLTFLoader ` - maybe just use `new GLTFLoader()`?

Comment: so I remove the import { GLTFLoader } from "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.121.1/examples/jsm/loaders/GLTFLoader.js" didnt really understand what you said

Comment: No, I was suggesting changing it to `let loader = new GLTFLoader()`. In case it's helpful, I'm seeing a similar issue listed here: https://discourse.threejs.org/t/there-is-no-gltfloader-in-three-module/16117